# Java question (about action)

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and saw a question that I don't know how to solve - 
the question is - 
'write a function that get an action, when the first thread enters the function - it will enable the action and then return true and exit. all other threads that enter the function would wait until the first thread finish it's action, and then they will do nothing and return false; '

I write this so far ( with help of stackoverflow useres) , but I have no idea what these action is and how to activate it:

```
public boolean doAction(Action doThis)
{
        synchronized (Ex1.lockit) // synchronize on the flag so that other threads arriving here, will be forced to wait
        { 
            if(!flag) // This condition is true only for the first thread.
            {
               flag = true; //set the flag so that other threads will not invoke doX.
         //      here I need to activate the action somehow;           
               return true;
            }
        }
        return false;    
}
```

Comment: What they want is for you to perform an action once and only once, the first thread performs the action and returns true, other thread wait for it to finish and return false; You can use a `Runnable` to pass an action.

Comment: Where is the original question posted? Can you please reproduce it here in its entirety? At the moment, I'm confused about the question requiring execute-only-once or execute-only-when-first-method-is-successful semantics from an answer.

Comment: Sounds like an attempt to create similar functionality to that of the EventQueue, but for Actions instead of Runnables. Does that sound about right?

Comment: the question isn't at English so I can't post it..

Comment: The question is not so clear to me either, I though maybe there is a way to activate "Action" (and not other types ) but apparently there isn't such a way.. but still - thank you